# Web2py - where to find big OS project

Tags: web-applications, web2py

Where i can find a (relatively big) open source project made with web2py?

Specifically, I am looking for a **management software**, so I can learn how to architecture big application in web2py. 
My aim is to write a **scalar** BE with 3 or more level of **user hyerarchy** with only a product.

Since now, I have found only small example of web2py application, that do not fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily in your genre, but these are fairly large apps:

- [Sahana Eden](http://eden.sahanafoundation.org/)
- [Movuca](https://github.com/rochacbruno/Movuca)